# "replace by" Vs "replace with"

Tags: british-english

As a step to renovation he has decided to replace old furniture by/ with new one.
I'm little confused in this sentence .
can you describe it ?

Answer (score 2):

There are already numerous discussions on Quora and Stackexchange about "replace by" vs "replace with". You may like to take a look at those. The rule seems to be the following:

1. If you are using the active voice, and referring to objects, then "with":

> Tom replaced the TV with a newer one.

2. If you are using the passive voice, and referring to roles, then "by":

> Tom was replaced by Bill in the role of bank manager.

3. Mixing and matching the above cases. What happens if you use the passive voice, referring to objects?

> the TV was replaced with a newer one. OR
>
> the TV was replaced by a newer one.

This is less clear. I would tend to prefer "with". However, they are both plausible answers.

4. What happens if you use the active voice, referring to roles?

> The bank president replaced Tom with Bill in the role of bank manager.

"With" should be used in the active construction.

Next, "furniture" is uncountable. Should "one" or "ones" follow "furniture"?
- "one" is singular
- "ones" is plural
- neither fits for an uncountable. So, lets look for alternatives:

> As a step to renovation he has decided to replace all the old furniture.
>   As a step to renovation he has decided to replace all the old furniture with brand new items from Nebraska Furniture Mart.
>   As a step to renovation he has decided to replace all the old furniture with new furniture.  (correct, however a bit repetitive)
>   As a step to renovation he has decided to replace the old table with a new one. (switch to singular)

Comment: It's also quite common to just end the sentence with *new*, as in *out with the old, in with the new*. Or *he has decided to replace the old furniture with new*.